# How to increase the size of File Attachment in Drupal

Tags: drupal-6

I am attaching a file in a node in drupal using File Attachment. But it is not allowing me to upload a file greater than 1MB. I want to upload a file of 50MB. How to increase this size. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add the below to the relevant php.ini file (recommended, if you have access). Note that for some hosts this is a system-wide setting. However, for hosts running PHP as a CGI script with suexec (for example) you may be able to put these directives in a php.ini file in your Drupal root directory.

- `upload_max_filesize = 50M`
- `post_max_size = 50M`

Add the below to your .htaccess file in your Drupal root directory.

- `php_value upload_max_filesize 50M`
- `php_value post_max_size 50M`

Comment: I am using GoDaddy, I dont have access to PHP.INI.

Comment: read 
Add the below to your .htaccess file in your Drupal root directory.
o php_value upload_max_filesize 50M
o php_value post_max_size 50M

Answer (score 0):

Apart the limit set by PHP, there is also a limit set by Drupal, which is per role. Once you changed the limit set by PHP, you should also change the limit set by Drupal, to get the desired effect.

Answer (score 0):

"Administer » Site configuration » File uploads" ( /admin/settings/uploads ). 
You can set Drupal limit per each role. The Drupal settings cannot be larger than those permitted by PHP, but may be smaller if you haven't updated them, so remember to check there also, after updating the php.ini.